# CD/DVD Drive does not work - Compaq 6715B

Tags: laptop, dvd, compact-disc, optical-drive

I'm unable to get any activity from the CD/DVD drive on my Compaq 6715B laptop. I've done some research and see where others experiencing the error recommend removing content from the following key {4D36E965-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}. This doesn't work even though I vaguely recall doing something similar a few years back.

The behavior is strange as there is no error message when I double click the drive from "My Computer"

When I try to use the "Run" dialog I get the following.

> V:\ is not accessible.
>
> The request could not be performed because of n I/O device error.

The drive may just be old but I'm wondering if there is a fix.

Answer (score 0):

I'd replace the drive.

CD-ROMs don't usually break due to wonky software configurations.  The software drivers don't have a ton of settings and are very mature.

This is almost definitely a hardware error.

Comment: I'd be inclined to believe you but have seen where deleting a key in the registry solved a previous issue
support.microsoft.com/kb/314060

But I've already done that, so you're very likely right. I was hoping for a quick fix to install an OS before the day starts but I'll have to make do :)

Comment: That registry setting just tells the OS the name of the driver. It's clear that your OS install has the driver installed.

Comment: The instructions specifically mentioned deleting a value called "UpperFilters" to fix a particular behaviour so I wouldn't say it just tells the OS the name of the driver.

It worked in the past but I agree that in this case it is most likely a hardware fault. I bought a USB Drive and created a bootable  USB so the world is OK again.

Comment: "Filters" are drivers.  I didn't make that clear in my comment. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545890(v=vs.85).aspx